Ansible Constructed
I am trying to create dynamic inventories using the constructed plugin, but I am facing an issue. I have to specify both the classic inventory with the hosts and the constructed inventory for it to work. Even if I use -i inventory/ with the directory containing both inventories, it doesn't change anything.
[star_wars]

[star_wars:children]
customer
proxmox

[customer:children]
luke_skywalker

[luke_skywalker]
proxmox-01

[proxmox]

proxmox-01
inventory/constructed.yml
---
plugin: constructed
strict: true

groups:
  bases: "'proxmox' in group_names"`

Result :
ansible-playbook -i inventory  task/test.yml

PLAY [Display group names for each host] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show group names] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [proxmox-01] => {
    "msg": "Host proxmox-01 is in groups: ['luke_skywalker', 'production', 'proxmox', 'star_wars']"

just only on inventory :
ansible-playbook -i inventory/inventory.yml -i inventory/constructed.yml  task/test.yml 

PLAY [Display group names for each host] **************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show group names] *******************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [proxmox-01] => {
    "msg": "Host proxmox-01 is in groups: ['bases', 'luke_skywalker', 'production', 'proxmox', 'star_wars']"


Ansible.cfg :
`[defaults]
roles_path = ./roles:~/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles
collections_paths = ./collections:~/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections

[inventory]
enable_plugins = ini, constructed

I would like passe on inventory  i know is possible, i read docs, its an error for me.
thanks for watching
i tried remove, rename constructed, nothing help me

Given the inventory
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── constructed.yml
└── hosts

shell> cat inventory/hosts 
[star_wars]

[star_wars:children]
customer
proxmox

[customer:children]
luke_skywalker

[luke_skywalker]
proxmox-01

[proxmox]
proxmox-01

shell> cat inventory/constructed.yml 
plugin: constructed
strict: true
groups:
  bases: "'proxmox' in group_names"

The files in the directory inventory are evaluated in alphabetic order. The file constructed.yml is evaluated before the file hosts. As a result, there is no group bases because there are no group_names when constructed.yml is evaluated
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    star_wars:
      children:
        customer:
          children:
            luke_skywalker:
              hosts:
                proxmox-01: {}
        proxmox:
          hosts:
            proxmox-01: {}

Make sure hosts is evaluated before constructed.yml if you want to use the groups from hosts. For example,
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-hosts
└── 02-constructed.yml

Then you get what you want
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --list --yaml
all:
  children:
    bases:
      hosts:
        proxmox-01: {}
    star_wars:
      children:
        customer:
          children:
            luke_skywalker:
              hosts:
                proxmox-01: {}
        proxmox:
          hosts:
            proxmox-01: {}

